# Is there any other way to destruct objects when they leave the function scope?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am following a "Learn OpenGL" book, and it is said that after linking individual shaders and compiling a shader program, we do not need the individual shaders anymore. Although it may be not entirely true in the more complex world of computer graphics, assume it is.

Now, when building the `Shader` and `ShaderProgram` classes, I want to implement this "destruct after not needed" behaviour, that is after `ShaderProgram` constructor finishes its job, vertex and fragment shader objects destructor should be called.

I can easily achieve such by using `std::unique_ptr<Shader>` and moving it into the `ShaderProgram` constructor.

I am just curious if there is a way to do it without using `std::unique_ptr`.

This is the example code I currently have:

```cpp
class Shader {
public: 
    Shader(){\\creating a shader}
   ~Shader(){glDeleteShader(id);}
   /* some methods */
private:
    unsigned int id;
};

class ShaderProgram {
public: 
    ShaderProgram(std::unique_ptr<Shader> vertex, std::unique_ptr<Shader> fragment){\\create a shader}
   ~ShaderProgram(){glDeleteProgram(id);}
   /*some methods*/
private:
    unsigned int id;
};
```

Comment: What's wrong with `unique_ptr`? It seems to be well suited to what you want to do.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, I simply was curious about the alternatives.

Comment: Ok, nothing wrong with being curious. I edited the question to make that a little clearer. Also, I removed the "thank you" part of the question. There's no harm in being polite, but for a Q&A site, it can be distracting, hope that's ok. Also, you might want to edit the question title, since it doesn't really summarize the question you're asking.

Comment: To create an object and immediately destroy it, just “call” the constructor: `MyType(whatever);`.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it without smart pointers. Incorporate move semantics in the Shader object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `glDeleteShader(id)` after you link it in your ShaderProgram constructor, no need to define a Shader class to hold this temporary object.